# How to boot Windows DVD without UEFI

Tags: windows-7, laptop, boot, uefi, efi

I searched the web, but didn't find anything.

I formated my single partition (300GB) to mbr partition table (it used gpt before). Now I want to install windows 7 but I can't because:

```
Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR
partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks.
```

I guess there is a way to boot the Windows DVD without UEFI, but how? In my bios I did not found anything that contains the word "EFI". So how can I install Windows 7 with mbr?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm using a usb DVD drive to install windows 7

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved this yet, or if anyone else finds this thread, you have to convert to GPT:

1. When installing at the partition screen hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.
2. At the prompt type `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type `list disk`  (Not the number of the disk you want to use)
4. Type `select disk X`  where is `X` is the number of the disk you want to use.
5. Type `clean`
6. Type `convert gpt`

Be warned though, this will clear out the partition table on the drive; make sure you have a backup before attempting this if you have important data

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer did not answer the question, he said he was previously using GPT and wanted to boot via UEFI.

I am also searching for same answer but unsure which option to pick in bios whether to just select via boot menu or if there is a more advanced option but i have this instructions to convert to MBR from GPT, saem as above basically but using MBR instead....

```
From BIOS select to boot the windows dvd without UEFI
Go To repair Options
Select Command Prompt and enter this:
    1. diskpart
    2.list disk
    3.select disk 0
    4.clean
    5.convert mbr
    6.create partition primary
    7.select partition 1
    8.format fs=ntfs quick
```

This will format your drive remember... once done boot from windows disc in normal way via boot menu and install.

Comment: This is exactly what Taquito Sensei answer describes.

Comment: To comment on someone elses' answer, you should use comments (also, answers sort themselves according to votes; "previous answer" is subject to change)

Comment: Its not exactly what Taquito describes. He tells him how to convert to GPT, which the OP said he didn't want. He already that. He wants MBR, which boss clearly describes. The answers are not the same. Why would you downvote?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know:

If Eprom/Firmware is BIOS: you can install win 7 with mbr table and win 10 with mbr (in fact BIOS could boot gpt disks, but microsoft has made it difficult)

If Eprom/Firmware is efi+csm (Compatibility Support Module) :you can install win 7 with mbr table and win 10 with mbr/gpt

If Eprom/Firmware is EFI without CSM: maybe you can install win7 with mbr with workarounds (no int10 support, so video bug, etc) and you can install win 10 with gpt table

However, in certain situations it might be necessary for a GPT partition layout to have an "MBR view" overlayed. This is called Hybrid MBR/GPT. Using a hybrid partition table might be necessary when dual-booting operating systems that are blind to a GPT-partitioned disk (for example, installing dual boot in apple computers - macos + windows)

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete and recreate the partitions on the drive.

- Once you boot up to the installer choose custom
- Select each partition that is visible and then choose delete at the boom (advanced)
- Once you have 1 volume of unallocated space, select it and hit Create Partition
- You can choose the default or the change the size to your liking

After this just run through the install normally.

Comment: Can you provide more detail to your single sentence?